# C#/.NET json serializer in client profile?

Tags: .net, json

Is there a JSON de/serializer in .NET client profile? or is including System.Web.Extensions.dll or json.net (3rd party, its pretty solid) my only option?

I would hope there is something built into the client profile by now (2012 with .NET 4.5)

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer? according to msdn it's supported in client profile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [no longer a client profile in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So feel free to use JSON.NET. Or `JavaScriptSerializer`. Or whatever.

By the way the new WebApi HttpClient uses JSON.NET so apparently Microsoft are leaning towards it.

Comment: If JSON.NET told why serialization failed it would be absolutely perfect. I use both (other being JavaScriptSerializer) depending on my project.